# In Capybara, how can I select a dynamically generated element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I want to select the following element:

```
<tr class="tr_even" id="13-hey-guys">
```

I want to select it by its id which is a dynamically generated concatenation of an object's id and its name.

When I use this line capture it:

```
within('tr id=\"#{item.id}-#{item.name.downcase}\"') do
    ...
```

I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: within('tr id=\"#{item.id}-#{item.name.downcase}\"') do
 Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:
   unexpected '=' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x0000010835f210 @type=:DESCENDANT_SELECTOR, @value=[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x0000010835f4e0 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["tr"]>, #<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x0000010835f2b0 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["id"]>]>]'
```

How do I capture my element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Capybara` uses CSS to find the elements.

I believe that the right way to find that element should be:

```
within("tr##{item.id}-#{item.name.downcase}") do
  ...
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's not working, I get Failure/Error: within('tr##{item.id}-#{item.name.downcase}') do
     Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError:
       unexpected '#' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node:0x0000010152e278 @type=:ELEMENT_NAME, @value=["tr"]>]'

Comment: @EricBaldwin Did you try with `"tr##{item.id}-#{item.name.downcase}"` instead of `'tr##{item.id}-#{item.name.downcase}'`?

Comment: Using double quotes gave me the "unable to find css..." error.  It still isn't working, but that syntax error is gone.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
    within("tr[@id=\"#{item.id}-#{item.name.downcase}\"]")
```

I haven't used within, but this is how elements in `find` normally can be specified.

By the way note that you have to use double quotes when you want to use `#{some_variable}`.